# Function for Updating text and blinking at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following problem.

the function below starts by filling a percentage bar, then goes and shows text on the same bar, (show "first text" and then blinks 2 times and shows then "second text").

what I would like is that in each blink it updates the text so the result be.

"First text" - Blink - "another text" - Blink - "a different text" - Blink - "Second text"

is this possible to do? I've been trying messing with it, but I wasn't able to make it work.

```
function updateStatusBar() {
    if (i < values.length-1) {
        i++;
        $(".progress-bar-color").css({width: parseInt(values[i].percent)+'%'});
        $('.status-percent').html(values[i].percent + '%');
        $('.status-text').html(values[i].text);
    } else {
        clearInterval(intId);
        $('.status-percent').css('visibility', 'hidden');


        $('.status-text').html('<strong>First text</strong>').addClass('align').fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('.status-text').html('<strong>Second text</strong>').addClass('searching');
            $('.status-text').fadeIn(500, function () {
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.outer1').fadeOut(500, function() {
                        $('.outer1').remove();
                        $('.outer2').fadeIn(500);
                    });
                }, 5000);
            });
        });

        $('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-red');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to check out jQuery's `.queue()`

Comment: how would that go?

Comment: OWuld you be able to help me? I've checked here: https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/      but I don't find how to do it, or if is it what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have your code is incorrect (`.fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(5‌​00)`). They're not supposed to be chained like you do now, all the fades are initiated *at the same moment*, this only works because jQuery makes a queue internally so this will work.

Apart from that this is not the way it should work, this is also inconvenient. If you want 1 more text, you have to change a lot of code for something very simple. When coding you should keep maintenance in the back of your mind.

This could be a push in the right direction:

```
var texts2loop = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']; // all the values we want    

function loopThroughTexts( $element, texts ){
    var text2show = 0;

    var textLooper = setInterval(function(){
        // Fade the bar out,
        $element.fadeOut(500, function(){
            // when animation is complete, change the text:
            $(this).html( texts[text2show]);
            // Fade back in:
            $(this).fadeIn(500);
            // Set the counter +1 so next round does next text
            texts2show++;
           // If we've had all texts, stop the interval:
            if( texts2show == texts.length ){
                clearInterval(textLooper);  
                // If you want to perform some functionallity when the texts are done, 
                // You could place that right here
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
}


loopThroughTexts( $('.status-text'), texts2loop);
```

Comment: uhm.. I'm not being able to make it work with this.. is there a way to change it in the code I have? I'm almost sure that the change will go in this area: 

  $('.status-text').html('<strong>First text</strong>').addClass('align').fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('.status-text').html('<strong>Second text</strong>').addClass('searching');

Comment: You should not to it that way. I've updated my answer a bit

Comment: I've made it into a function, you only need to set the values and call the function.

Comment: I'm sorry, thank you for your help, but I'm not being able to make it work :(